# How can i resolve <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden> on python anywere

Tags: python, telegram

i created a telegram bot that creates the news for a football rp but i get this error: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>
i'm using pythonanywhere and i know there is a whitelist but i am using the custom search api that should work here is the code

```
 search_query = quote(f"{giocatore} {squadra} giocatore")
        api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={CUSTOM_SEARCH_API_KEY}&cx={CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}&q={search_query}&searchType=image"

        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(api_url)
            data = json.load(response)
            image_url = data['items'][0]['link'] if 'items' in data and len(data['items']) > 0 else None

            if image_url:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, 'image.jpg')
                image = Image.open('image.jpg')
                news_message = get_news_message(giocatore, squadra, costo, stipendio, epicità)
                bot.send_photo(chat_id, image, caption=news_message)
            else:
                bot.send_message(chat_id, "Impossibile trovare un'immagine per il giocatore specificato.")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Errore durante la richiesta: {str(e)}")
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "Si è verificato un errore durante la richiesta.")

    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Si prega di fornire tutti i dati richiesti.")
```

of course i have put in the code the key and the id

when i enter the inputs the bot should send the news but he has problem on the image

Comment: Free accounts on PythonAnywhere need to use a proxy to access the external Internet, and it doesn't look like your code is using that.  What happens if you use the (proxy-aware) `requests` library instead of `urllib`?  If you still get the 403 error, what is in the body of the HTTP response?